# Chrome: Save as dialogue creates temp file in download directory, I want to change this location

Tags: google-chrome, temporary-files

I've set the download directory for Chrome to be my desktop, but that means that whenever I want to "Save As" it creates a temp file on my desktop until I select the final download destination and close the dialogue.

This is deeply frustrating since I browse windowed and I keep seeing the damn things pop up and disappear in the corner of my eye, is there any way to change the directory in which temp files are created in this manner?

Comment: The .temp file is created because Chrome actually starts the download even before you choose where to save the file, therefore it assumes you want to save to your default location until you tell it otherwise. Without delving into the inner workings of Chrome, I would make a downloads directory on the desktop and point to that instead.